# Avoid Firebase database JSON File being public- Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

In my current job It's been reported that the firebase db is public (you can see the complete json if you know the URL(see image)),that's because the rules are read=true ,write=true ,as you can imagine.

I proposed implementing Authentication and  then changing the rules to read,true ="auth.uid !== null"
however it was rejected by my superiors because they say it takes too long(months) for all the users to install a new version and if we implement authentication and change the rules , users using previous versions won't be able to have access to the db

[image: public db example]

I really need help with this problem, they don't want the db to be accesible openly(see image) and at the same time we cannot implement authentication because of the reason explained above

I was thinking of, if exists ,a way to block web connections  or connections out of the apps that belong to the firebase project
if anyone knows a way to handle this problem (without releasing  a new app version) please comment, i'd really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

> I was thinking of, if exists ,a way to block web connections or [connections] out of the apps that belong to the firebase project

That's exactly what Firebase App Check can do, so I recommend reading up on that.

> (without releasing a new app version)

That's may not possible. Since you started by granting everyone in the world access to all data and now want to disallow that, you'll need to change your app to adhere to the new rules that you want to impose.

---

What you can (and should) do is to implement your security rules so that they allow exactly what your code requires, and nothing more. This is known as the [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) and is typically easiest to implement if you apply it from the start.

1. Start with an app with no Firebase related code and security rules that disallow all access to the database.
2. Implement the first simple use-case in the application code.
3. See if being disallowed by the security rules.
4. Change the rules to allow just the one use-case, but disallow all other access.
5. Go back to step 2 until you're done.

Comment: thanks bro ,yes  i had read about AppCheck but  it's a shame it needs kind of initialization  in code , I think that feature should work  by activating in the console only, any way I will have to tell my superiors that there's no way to achieve what they want